# Auxiliary Verb with Piacere

Tags: auxiliary-verb

My question is about the use of the use of the auxiliary verb "avere" with "piacere". I have always been taught to use "essere" but a book teaching "piacere" using "avere" has been brought to my attention.

I am including a link to the book on Amazon [https://www.amazon.com/LL-Italian-Conversational-Approach-Verbs/dp/0517885301](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0517885301). I've tried to copy and paste the page sent to me, but that doesn't seem to work. Below, is a partial "copy" of the page.

> 103 piacere to like, to be pleasing 
>   Present Perfect 
>   ho piaciuto                            abbiamo piaciuto  
>   hai piaciuto             
>    avete piaciuto  
>   ha piaciuto                               hanno piaciuto

It shows the present perfect as

> ebbi piaciuto           
>   avemmo piaciuto etc.

Comment: Does this book give any example?

Comment: Perhaps the phrase *ho piacere*, but this is not a case of auxiliary verb.

Comment: Yes, in the phrase _"ho piacere"_ , piacere is not a verb, it's a noun (precisely, it is a substantive use of the verb) . Could be translated with _I've got the pleasure_

Comment: Or it might refer to the deliberately wrong _Ti ha piaciato?_ by turn-of-20th-century comedian Ettore Petrolini. It would mean “Did you like it?”, but both the auxiliary verb and the form of the participle are funnily incorrect.

Comment: That seems really strange to me!

Comment: In modern Italian it sounds ridiculously wrong, something a bad-taste sketch about an ignorant person would say. I can't rule off, however, that  the auxiliary _avere_ has been used in some past, possibly regional, variation of Italian, and Google Books would seem to suggest so (but we should ascertain the literacy of the few authors who used, say, _ha piaciuto_).

Comment: On the other hand, looking for _piaciuto_ in Boccaccio's _Decameron_, [we never find an auxiliary other than _essere_](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Speciale:Ricerca?search=piaciuto&prefix=Decameron&fulltext=Cerca+in+questo+libro&fulltext=Search&searchToken=6qs2ghpjqc8szwpvukvpo5zfi).

Comment: I am also in the group finding *ho piaciuto* weird and wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The verb *piacere* has a very peculiar behavior in Italian: it is intransitive and the person/thing that's liked is the subject, while the person who likes is the “complemento di termine” (corresponding to the Latin *dative*).

So *I like cakes* becomes *mi piacciono i dolci* (usually but not mandatorily the subject comes last), where *mi* is the weak form for *a me*.

The auxiliary verb for *piacere* is *essere*, as reported in all dictionaries ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piacere2/), [Sabatini-Coletti](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/P/piacere_1.shtml), [Gabrielli](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/P/piacere.php) are a few examples).

So “ho piaciuto” is at the very least uncommon, for not saying wrong. Maybe it is used somewhere, but a conversation manual should stick to the most common conventions. Do you remember the [Monty Python sketch about phrasebooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6D1YI-41ao)?